# R studio add geom_abline with specified intercept

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I want to have a line that crosses the chart at 45 degrees no matter what the x and y scale is. In this example the intercept for the abline shoud be around x=-3 and y=-0.5.

Below a few line of code:

```
x <- seq(1,10,1)
y <- sample(1:100, 10, replace=T)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(slope = 45) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10), limits = c(-10,10)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10), limits = c(-2,10))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just add

```
ggplot2::annotation_custom(grid::linesGrob())
```

to your plot.

So you can do this:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggplot2::annotation_custom(grid::linesGrob())
```

[image]

or this

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_histogram() + 
  ggplot2::annotation_custom(grid::linesGrob())
```

[image]

If you want to change the look of the line you need to change the grob:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggplot2::annotation_custom(grid::linesGrob(gp = grid::gpar(col = "red", lty = 2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is indeed what I was looking for> Do you by chance know also how to put the line in red and dashed? I've been playing around for a bit and still did not manage

Comment: @Jordan_b I think in your call to linesGrob you do linesGrob(gp=gpar(col = “red”, lty = 2))

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also installed the relative package (grid)

Comment: Do you by chance know how to colour the part below the line by red? with a certain alpha (not full red in order to keep seeing the dots) ?

Comment: @Jordan_b ensure you have done `library(grid)` then try adding `+ annotation_custom(polygonGrob(x=c(0,1,1,0), y=c(0,0,1,0), gp=gpar(fill="red", alpha=0.3)))` to your plot. Change the alpha value to make the grob more or less transparent